# document.querySelectorAll is not taking place

Tags: html, jquery, reactjs, jsx

I just started using react js so im sorry if my question shouldn't be asked here.
I wrote some JSX inside the return function and i thought i wanted to write some javascript to that html (JSX) that i wrote but it doesnt seem like its taking any affects. I honestly dont know if im missing anything. Please let me know.

```
import React from "react";
import "./Pingbutton.scss";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
const pingbutton = () => {
  
  document.querySelectorAll(".button").forEach((button) => {
    button.textContent = "This is my new text";
    let getVar = (variable) =>
      getComputedStyle(button).getPropertyValue(variable);
  
    button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (!button.classList.contains("active")) {
        button.classList.add("active");
  
        gsap.to(button, {
          keyframes: [
            {
              "--left-wing-first-x": 50,
              "--left-wing-first-y": 100,
              "--right-wing-second-x": 50,
              "--right-wing-second-y": 100,
              duration: 0.2,
              onComplete() {
                gsap.set(button, {
                  "--left-wing-first-y": 0,
                  "--left-wing-second-x": 40,
                  "--left-wing-second-y": 100,
                  "--left-wing-third-x": 0,
                  "--left-wing-third-y": 100,
                  "--left-body-third-x": 40,
                  "--right-wing-first-x": 50,
                  "--right-wing-first-y": 0,
                  "--right-wing-second-x": 60,
                  "--right-wing-second-y": 100,
                  "--right-wing-third-x": 100,
                  "--right-wing-third-y": 100,
                  "--right-body-third-x": 60,
                });
              },
            },
            {
              "--left-wing-third-x": 20,
              "--left-wing-third-y": 90,
              "--left-wing-second-y": 90,
              "--left-body-third-y": 90,
              "--right-wing-third-x": 80,
              "--right-wing-third-y": 90,
              "--right-body-third-y": 90,
              "--right-wing-second-y": 90,
              duration: 0.2,
            },
            {
              "--rotate": 50,
              "--left-wing-third-y": 95,
              "--left-wing-third-x": 27,
              "--right-body-third-x": 45,
              "--right-wing-second-x": 45,
              "--right-wing-third-x": 60,
              "--right-wing-third-y": 83,
              duration: 0.25,
            },
            {
              "--rotate": 55,
              "--plane-x": -8,
              "--plane-y": 24,
              duration: 0.2,
            },
            {
              "--rotate": 40,
              "--plane-x": 45,
              "--plane-y": -180,
              "--plane-opacity": 0,
              duration: 0.3,
              onComplete() {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  button.removeAttribute("style");
                  gsap.fromTo(
                    button,
                    {
                      opacity: 0,
                      y: -8,
                    },
                    {
                      opacity: 1,
                      y: 0,
                      clearProps: true,
                      duration: 0.3,
                      onComplete() {
                        button.classList.remove("active");
                      },
                    }
                  );
                }, 2000);
              },
            },
          ],
        });
  
        gsap.to(button, {
          keyframes: [
            {
              "--text-opacity": 0,
              "--border-radius": 0,
              "--left-wing-background": getVar("--primary-darkest"),
              "--right-wing-background": getVar("--primary-darkest"),
              duration: 0.1,
            },
            {
              "--left-wing-background": getVar("--primary"),
              "--right-wing-background": getVar("--primary"),
              duration: 0.1,
            },
            {
              "--left-body-background": getVar("--primary-dark"),
              "--right-body-background": getVar("--primary-darkest"),
              duration: 0.4,
            },
            {
              "--success-opacity": 1,
              "--success-scale": 1,
              duration: 0.25,
              delay: 0.25,
            },
          ],
        });
      }
    });
  });
  
  return (
    <>
      <body>
        <button className="button">
          <span className="default">Ping</span>
          <span className="success">Pinged!</span>
          <div className="left"></div>
          <div className="right"></div>
        </button>

        <a
          className="dribbble"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          href="https://dribbble.com/ai"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <img
            src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/assets/dribbble-ball-mark-2bd45f09c2fb58dbbfb44766d5d1d07c5a12972d602ef8b32204d28fa3dda554.svg"
            alt=""
          ></img>
        </a>
      
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            width="72"
            height="72"
            viewBox="0 0 72 72"
          >
            <path d="M67.812 16.141a26.246 26.246 0 0 1-7.519 2.06 13.134 13.134 0 0 0 5.756-7.244 26.127 26.127 0 0 1-8.313 3.176A13.075 13.075 0 0 0 48.182 10c-7.229 0-13.092 5.861-13.092 13.093 0 1.026.118 2.021.338 2.981-10.885-.548-20.528-5.757-26.987-13.679a13.048 13.048 0 0 0-1.771 6.581c0 4.542 2.312 8.551 5.824 10.898a13.048 13.048 0 0 1-5.93-1.638c-.002.055-.002.11-.002.162 0 6.345 4.513 11.638 10.504 12.84a13.177 13.177 0 0 1-3.449.457c-.846 0-1.667-.078-2.465-.231 1.667 5.2 6.499 8.986 12.23 9.09a26.276 26.276 0 0 1-16.26 5.606A26.21 26.21 0 0 1 4 55.976a37.036 37.036 0 0 0 20.067 5.882c24.083 0 37.251-19.949 37.251-37.249 0-.566-.014-1.134-.039-1.694a26.597 26.597 0 0 0 6.533-6.774z"></path>
          </svg>
        </a>
      </body>
    </>
  );
};

export default pingbutton;
```

the file is already called inside the app.js file. The problem is with the javascript code that im writing above the return function that is supposed to affect the button by calling it, but is not.*I already downloaded JQuery*

Note: I tried calling the html using document.getElementsByClassName("button").forEach((button) => { but also didnt work.

Thank you.

Comment: why are you using DOM methods in react? https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html